# ng-material-multilevel-menu ERROR NullInjectorError: No provider for MultilevelMenuService. Angular 12

Tags: angular

I am using angular 12 and want to implement the `ng-material-multilevel-menu`, I followed this [link](https://plugins.codershood.info/#/plugins/ngmm-plugin) to implement the multilevel menu.

It complied successfully but still showing error in the browser.

By doing some google I found that adding `ɵb` in the `app.module.ts` will solve the problem but it didn't work out in my case.

**Error that I am getting:**

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MultilevelMenuService -> MultilevelMenuService -> MultilevelMenuService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MultilevelMenuService!
```

**app.html**

```
<ng-material-multilevel-menu [configuration]='config' [items]='appitems' (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)">
</ng-material-multilevel-menu>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  appitems = [
    {
      label: 'Item 1 (with Font awesome icon)',
      faIcon: 'fab fa-500px',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Item 1.1',
          link: '/item-1-1',
          faIcon: 'fab fa-accusoft'
        },
        {
          label: 'Item 1.2',
          faIcon: 'fab fa-accessible-icon',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Item 1.2.1',
              link: '/item-1-2-1',
              faIcon: 'fas fa-allergies'
            },
            {
              label: 'Item 1.2.2',
              faIcon: 'fas fa-ambulance',
              items: [
                {
                  label: 'Item 1.2.2.1',
                  link: 'item-1-2-2-1',
                  faIcon: 'fas fa-anchor'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 2',
      icon: 'alarm',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Item 2.1',
          link: '/item-2-1',
          icon: 'favorite'
        },
        {
          label: 'Item 2.2',
          link: '/item-2-2',
          icon: 'favorite_border'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 3',
      link: '/item-3',
      icon: 'offline_pin'
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 4',
      link: '/item-4',
      icon: 'star_rate',
      hidden: true
    }
  ];

  config = {
    paddingAtStart: true,
    classname: 'my-custom-class',
    listBackgroundColor: 'rgb(208, 241, 239)',
    fontColor: 'rgb(8, 54, 71)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(208, 241, 239)',
    selectedListFontColor: 'red',
  };

ngOnInit() {}


selectedItem($event:any) {
  console.log($event);
}
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-material-multilevel-menu": "^5.5.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule,ɵb } from 'ng-material-multilevel-menu';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
     .....
    NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule
  ],
  providers: [ɵb],
```

So is this some dependency issue or some version. Also if this cannot be implemented in the angular-12 so is there any other library for angular-12 that work like this so that I can implement the multi level dropdown in angular.

Comment: Why don't you try angular/material treeview component.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the service in providers. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#specifying-a-provider-token Also in the link you provided I don't see a reason to import/provide `ɵb`, may want to remove that.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
     .....
    NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule
  ],
  providers: [ɵb, NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule],
```

Comment: I tried this as well but still getting the same error, but thanks for replying.